# Joining tables and printing data using Laravel5

Tags: laravel-5, query-builder

Trying to print data about packages and properties belonging to every package.

Using a join table to join two other tables.

When trying to print each package with the separate properties belonging to each package, all the properties for all packages are printed for each package.

Controller method:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $packages = Package::all();

        $courses = DB::table('course_package')
        ->join('package', 'course_package.Package_Id', '=', 'package.Id')
        ->join('course', 'course_package.Course_Id', '=', 'course.Id')
        ->select('course_package.*', 'package.*')
        ->get();

        return View::make('admin.package.index')
            ->with('packages', $packages)
            ->with('courses', $courses);

    }
```

View:

```
@foreach($packages as $package)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $package->Id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $package->title }}</td>
        <td>{{ $package->description }}</td>
        <td>{{ $package->university }}</td>
        <td>{{ $package->faculty }}</td>
        @foreach($courses as $course)
            @if($course->Package_title = $package->title)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$course->Course_name}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endif
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

What do I need to do in order to print all courses belonging to a certain package together with the specific package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Laravel** ships with [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) out of the box, make use of it!

**Package** and **Course** are [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), with `course_package` as pivot table (Intermediate Table).

**package.php**

```
class Package extends Model
{
    public function courses() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course', 'course_package', 'Package_Id', 'Course_Id'); 
    }
}
```

**view**

```
@foreach ($packages as $package)
    ...
    @foreach ($package->courses as $course)
        ...
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: This will definitely be the best approach.